# Android Input Method Manager to get Numbers only keypad

Tags: android, android-edittext

We use

```
InputMethodManager imPharamcy = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imPharamcy .toggleSoftInput(0, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
```

to get the keyboard forcefully.
But the keyboard is not numbers only keyboard.
How do i get numbers only keyboard using inputMethod Manager.

In xml i have already given

```
   android:inputType="phone"
   android:imeOptions="actionNext"
```

the editText takes numbers only
Strangely in the emulator a number only keypad comes up but on a phone numbers and special charaters keypad comes

Comment: hey i am stuck at the same problem can you share your code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28978225/how-to-show-number-keyboard-on-custom-view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See below code:

```
    // TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER: Class for numeric text. This displays the numbers/symbols keyboard.
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

// TYPE_CLASS_PHONE: Class for a phone number. This displays the phone number keypad.
editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

Hope you got the point.

Comment: That wasn't the question. The question was how to get numbers only keyboard using `InputMethodManager` class, not the `TextView`. I need this for a Cordova app, where the WebView prevents keyboard from showing on focus and I need to force it to show using a plugin. Since it's a WebView and now a textbox, I need to use the `InputMethodManager` only, there are no TextViews to play with.