# How to show number keyboard on custom view

Tags: android, keyboard, android-custom-view

I created a custom view:

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout {...}
```

When user touch it, I show keyboard like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            requestFocus();
            showKeyboard(true);
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    public void showKeyboard(boolean show) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (show) {
          imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
        } else {
          imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

But how can I show a number keyboard, which user can only input digits, just like this for EditText?

```
mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
mEditText.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_FLAG_NO_EXTRACT_UI);
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5419766/how-to-capture-soft-keyboard-input-in-a-view

Answer (score 3):

You have to add an override for onCreateInputConnection

```
public class MyCustomView extends LinearLayout implements View.OnFocusChangeListener {

    //...

    // Make sure to call this from your constructor
    private void initialize(Context context) {
        setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        setFocusable(true);
        setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        if (hasFocus) {
            imm.showSoftInput(v, 0);
        } else {
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }

    // Here is where the magic happens
    @Override
    public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        outAttrs.inputType = InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
        outAttrs.imeOptions = EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE;
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Missing a return of type "InputConnection" in "onCreateInputConnection". It can be a simple "return null".

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
 EditText mEditText = new EditText(mContext);
 mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

and change

```
imm.showSoftInput(this, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

to

```
imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

i.e. rewrite your code as

```
if (show) {
    EditText mEditText = new EditText(mContext);
    mEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    imm.showSoftInput(mEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
}
```

replace `mContext` is your activity context.

Comment: Do you mean add an invisible EditText into my custom view, and make the EditText to be keyboard focus?

Comment: To show keyboard on the invisible EditText, I have to set keyboard focus to it, i.e, editText.requestFocus(), and all keyboard event will also be sent to the EditText. But I want to handle keyboard event in my custom view itself. How to do?

Comment: Also interested. Faced the same problem. Did you find any solution?